# comparative definitions of category and set

Tags: category-theory, set-theory, definition

I often use these concepts when I am working (I am a programmer), although the differences/similarities are a bit blurry in my head.

Does anyone have a concise definition of these mathematical concepts ?
What are their properties ?
Also how are meta-category/set related to them ?

I am not a mathematician but I am curious an interested in the subject. If you need to use an advanced concept in your explication, I don't mind looking for a definition on the internet, but hightly abstract mathematical concepts tend to scare me.

Thanks in advance for your help ! :)

Comment: @ArnaudD. So you are a mathematician AND a detective ? x)

Comment: @ArnaudD. I thought those were disctinct concepts in english, but I will consider them as synonyms now, thanks for the clarification

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I never said that maths could be translation invariant, my mistake comes from the fact that english is not my first language. Also I have already read the article on wikipedia, and I only end up with more questions : what is a collection, what is the difference between distinct and non-distinct objects, do sets have to be homogeneous (like, contain elements of the same type) ...

Comment: Thus, first point : Set [English] = Ensemble [French]. In math a *set* is whatever "corresponds" to the mathematical objects described by [set theory](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/set-theory/). The basic relation is that between an element that belongs to a set. An element can be itself a set and an element can belong to many different sets.

Comment: See also the post [What is a “formal definition” of a set?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/972236/what-is-a-formal-definition-of-a-set) as well as [What is the definition of a set?(https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1452425/what-is-the-definition-of-a-set)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA So a set is a generic container that can contain anything ? Is "belonging" the only essential relation of set theory ? Concerning the formal definition of a set, it's a bit technical, are axioms statement assumed to be absolute truths within a scope ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA In the second link, the best answer says that sets are atomic. But how can a container be atomic ? It's in its own nature not to be atomic, no ?. And it also states that they have no definition, how is it even possible ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks for the resource, it seems to be exhaustive and precise, although it is exactly what I do not want : it's way too long and technical for me. I just need a short sentence with a list of essential properties for both concepts. It's not that I don't enjoy reading books, but i simply do not have the knowledge to fully understand this one

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA So if I understand, sets are atomic because they cannot be defined in terms of elementary concepts, because they are elementary concepts themselves ? Can they be defined by their properties then (maybe the "belonging" relation ?) ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA And no, we do not learn programming languages by reading the specifications (even if they are sometimes really useful), it is a highly practical learning process that is really similar to natural languages :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding *set theory*, we may start with some elucidatory comments.

> [Set theory](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/set-theory/) is the mathematical theory of well-determined collections, called *sets*, of objects that are called *members*, or *elements*, of the set.
>
> *Pure* set theory deals exclusively with sets, so the only sets under consideration are those whose members are also sets.

We have to stress the fact that it is a *mathematical* theory.

It is also a very simple theory, from a conceptual point of view, because its "ontology" presupposes only the existence of sets and the description of their "mathematical behaviour" is made entirely in terms of only one relation: that of "being a member of" ($\in$).

> The notion of set is so simple that it is usually introduced informally, and regarded as self-evident. In set theory, however, as is usual in mathematics, sets are given axiomatically, so their existence and basic properties are postulated by the appropriate axioms.
>
> The axioms of set theory imply the existence of a set-theoretic universe so rich that all mathematical objects can be construed as sets. Also, the formal language of pure set theory allows one to formalize all mathematical notions and arguments.
>
> > Thus, set theory has become the standard foundation for mathematics, as every mathematical object can be viewed as a set, and every theorem of mathematics can be logically deduced from the axioms of set theory.

---

From this point on, we have to start with the exposition of the mathematical theory itself, and with the statement of some basic principles derived from our intuition of what it means:

> to "collect" into our thought some distinct objects and manage them as a single, well defined object [*freely derived from the well-known* [Cantor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georg_Cantor)'s *quote* (*Beiträge*, I, 1895)].

Comment: Thank you very much, set theory is much clear in my mind now :D

Comment: I have marked your answer as "useful", but it is not displayed since i haven't enough reputation apparently

Comment: I am really satisfied with it, I just need to learn what are categories now. I've read they were considered as something even more fundamental than sets, but I do not understand much more